# Laravel console command catch signal from terminal

Tags: php, laravel, console, signals, laravel-5

I'm trying to catch signals in terminal. I know that I can use `pcntl_signal()` function but it doesn't work for me.

I am trying with this code:

```
public function handle() {
    pcntl_signal(SIGINT, function ($signo) {
        echo "CATCH!\n";
        exit;
    });

    while (true) { echo("!\n"); sleep(2); }
}
```

When I press `Ctrl+C` I don't see any result, because program still is working. What do I wrong?

I want to stop program after press `Ctrl+C` and call `__destruct()` method.

Comment: You need to close `pcntl_signal(.....);` What OS are you under ?

Comment: Could you update the code with the one you're actually running? The one you pasted will result in parse errors.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH @jedrzej.kurylo i forgot about `);` - my big fault

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the Laravel SignalableCommandInterface now

```php
class MyCommand extends Command implements SignalableCommandInterface
{

    public function handleSignal(int $signal): void
    {
        echo "CATCH!\n";
        exit;
    }

    // Which signals will be handled
    public function getSubscribedSignals(): array
    {
        return [SIGINT, SIGTERM];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`pcntl_signal()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php) function won't work without this line in your file:

```
declare(ticks = 1);
```

It should probably be at the top of the file, before the class definition.

A [tick](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php#control-structures.declare.ticks) is an event that occurs regularly during the program execution, and in this case each tick triggers the program to check the signals coming in. I think. I don't know why it's not enabled by default, possibly due to increased CPU load while it's in operation?

I've seen some assertions that ticks were deprecated after PHP 5.3, but I just tested in PHP 7.0.9 and can confirm that `pcntl_signal()` doesn't work without it.

Comment: Instead of `declare(ticks = 1)` you can call `pcntl_signal_dispatch()` at various points in your code. Basically, it checks if the application has received a signal and if so dispatches the signal handler registered with `pcntl_signal()`.